# How to force layout of collection view without compromising on the performance?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

Here's my problem. I have a UICollectionViewCell having an image View. The image is downloaded from a link. The images are of different sizes and I want the collectionView cell size to change with the image size. I am currently accomplishing this by forcing the layout inside

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

by placing this line of code in it

```
collectionViewTrending.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
```

The below `UICollectionViewDelegate` function

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

is handling the resizing of the cell.
Though this is working but it definitely is NOT efficient. It is inefficient because scrolling on the collectionView is taking longer and it is not smooth.  Is there any way in which I can resize the cell without degrading the performance?

Comment: `but it definitely is NOT efficient.`  In what way?  What is inefficient?  What are your performance requirements and what have you measured the current performance at?

Comment: I haven't measured it. I have tested it on my phone and I see that scrolling down collectionView is taking longer and is not smooth. From the perspective of a user, this is pretty irksome.

Comment: You need to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36826638/edit) and update it to include a description of the behavior that is problematic, as well as the actual code that is causing this behavior (which requires measuring).

Answer (score 0):

Remove that line--collectionViewTrending.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath]) first..
Then set sizeForItem method of collectionView properly..It will work fine..